# wxWidgets convert wchar_t** to char**

Tags: c++, type-conversion, wxwidgets

I'm trying to capture the application `argc` & `argv` using the following code:

```
int       wx_argc = wxGetApp().argc;
wchar_t** wx_argv = wxGetApp().argv;
```

then I need to pass it to another function that need `argv` in `char**` type,

How can the `wx_argv` be converted from type `wchar_t**` to `char**` ?

Comment: Using a for loop with an assignment inside.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

wchar_t* p = L"Ciao Mondo";
char    v[50];
wcstombs(v, p, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer depends on which encoding do you need the narrow (`char*`) string to be in. If this is the encoding of the current locale, then you could indeed just use `wcstombs()` as mentioned by @AngeloDM. Otherwise you can use either the methods of some `wxMBConv`-derived class directly (e.g. `wxMBConvUTF8` or `wxMBConvUTF16` for the specific encodings or `wxCSConv` which will try to convert to any supported charset you specify) or pass by [wxString](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Converting_everything_to_and_from_wxString).

In any case, this only takes care of the conversion from `wchar_t*` to `char*` and you still need to allocate your own `argc`-sized `char**` array and loop over all entries converting them one by one.